# Having Issue with Horizontal CSS Menu

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, menu

I'm having an issue with my Horizontal CSS Menu. The issue or bug is that on Internet Explorer & Firefox it doesn't line up straight with the logo, it's like a half space under. I can't seem to line it up. On Safari & Chrome it line up straight. Plus on IE there's an extra gap between the logo and the menu, it moves the menu towards to the logo. On the other browser it doesn't move it stays put.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="center" style="  
<a href="index.php"><img src="image/New.png" alt="" width="300" height="60"/></a>
<ul id="minitabs">
<li><a href="home.php"><u>Home</u></a></li>
<li><a href="news.php"><u>News</u></a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php"><u>Contact</u></a></li> 
</ul> 
</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
 .center {margin-left:0px;
          margin-right:0px;
          margin-top:0px;
          margin-bottom:0px;}

  ul#minitabs{list-style: none;margin: -25px 46px 0px 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
              border-bottom: 0px solid #CCC;font-weight: regular;
              font-family:Times New Roman; font-size: 14px;text-align: right;}
  ul#minitabs li{display: inline; border-bottom: 1px;
              margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 1px 5px 0px 5px;}
  ul#minitabs a{text-decoration:none; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
                border-bottom: 0px solid #FFF;color: #000000;}
  ul#minitabs a#current{border-color: #F60;color: #000000;}
  ul#minitabs a:hover{text-decoration:underline; text-color: #999999;}
```

So far I can't find a solution for this. I appreciate any explanation so I can learn how to manage this bug & an examples will also do so I can learn how to fixed this bug.

Thanks

Comment: I assume the first line with the `div` is a typo? it's not finished

Comment: @Rodolfo, Thanks for the reply! No it's a div I was trying to move line up the logo with the menu meaning line it up

Comment: no what I mean is that it ends in `style="`  Also, its id is 'center', but in the css you do a `.center` which applies to something with a class 'center', not id 'center', so either the css should be `#center` or the div should be `class="center"`

Comment: @Rodolfo, Thanks for the reply again! Yes you made a point, I was just so focus on lining up that the .center is actually #center. Thanks for the reminder. I will change the post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the browsers are formatting your borders differently. Try putting your menu within a div to see.

```
<div style="height: 60px; overflow:hidden;">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You mean the borders are acting differently? I already have div for the logo. I'm gonna to try to put that code into the div container that I have already. I will test it out and see will be work. Thanks for the example & explanation!

Comment: @ user1473061. I try your example and it didn't work either. It still not lining up.

Comment: @LightM1 I don't have enough points to commend on your last post to redelman431 but if you put img{float:left;} then you are telling it to format every image with float:left;. Your solution to that part will be to put this in your html for the image you want to float <img src="" class="left"/> and this in your css .left{float:left;}

Comment: @LightM1 I'm also a little confused with what is happening on your site. Can you please post a link?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will make some adjustment!

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to put the nav next to the logo or under it? If your putting it next to it, I found a solution. Do this:

HTML:

```
<div id="center">  
<a href="index.php"><img src="image/New.png" alt="" width="300" height="60"/></a>
<ul id="minitabs">
<li><a href="home.php"><u>Home</u></a></li>
    <li>&nbsp<a href="news.php"><u>News</u></a></li>
    <li>&nbsp<a href="contact.php"><u>Contact</u></a></li> 
</ul> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {float:left;}
li { float:left; margin-top: /*amount you want to move nav down*/;}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Otherwise if you want it below the logo just change the CSS to this

```
li { float:left; margin-left: /*amount you want to move nav right*/;}​
```

​

Comment: @ Ross, Thanks for the reply. Yes, I am trying to move the nav next to the logo. That's why there's a div tag for the logo. I was trying to line it up with the nav. But my intention is to put it next to the logo. Thanks for the example! I will test it out now. Thanks

Comment: @ redelman431. I try your example and it didn't work. It still not lining up.

Comment: Could it be a browser issue? if so try checking your css and html validation http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @ redelman431, my website is not done yet so there is some errors. I have articles that has images and I used "img" for the picture. When I put your img {float:left;}, it flow all images to the left. At that point I was a bit confused. If I have a logo that is "img" and my article have "img" tag also what is another solution? I be honest with you it did move everything to the left and moving the margin-left to line it up. It didn't, is it display:? I appreciate that you took time to reply back to help me resolve this bug. Thanks!